# Attribute 'MaxOccurs' cannot appear in element 'element'." In RAML defination

Tags: xml, mule, raml

I am getting this error while defining the Raml for Xml input however I get this error, I already know this question is answered for xsd but I don't have xsd in Raml

Can anyone suggest a solution of how to define array in xml design
as I already have gone through the below Url

https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#array-type

Input:

```
<numbers>
    <value>3</value>
    <value>2</value>
    <value>1</value>
</numbers>


#%RAML 1.0
title: Claim Request
version: 0.1
baseUri: http://localhost:8767/claim
mediaType: [ application/xml ]
protocols: HTTP
types:
  value:
    type: string
  numbers:
    type: value[]
    uniqueItems: true
/claimDemo:
  post: 
   body:
    type : numbers
   responses: 
    200:
     body: 
      application/json:
       example: |
              {
                "message" : "Hello World"
              }
```

Output:

```
Exception stack trace:
 org.mule.module.apikit.exception.BadRequestException: Error validating XML.     Error: s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'maxOccurs' cannot appear in element 'element'.
at  org.mule.module.apikit.HttpRestRequest.validateSchemaV2(HttpRestRequest.java:539)
at org.mule.module.apikit.HttpRestRequest.validateBody(HttpRestRequest.java:379)
at org.mule.module.apikit.HttpRestRequest.negotiateInputRepresentation(HttpRestRequest.java:353)
at org.mule.module.apikit.HttpRestRequest.validate(HttpRestRequest.java:125)
at org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractRouter.processRouterRequest(AbstractRouter.java:205)
```

Comment: Well, there's an XSD file somewhere that isn't a valid schema, and I guess your first task is to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation in: https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#xml-serialization-of-type-instances you can use the `wrapped` option which will allow you to avoid the problem you are facing with the definition here.

See the example below

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Claim Request
version: 0.1
baseUri: http://localhost:8767/claim
mediaType: [ application/xml ]
protocols: HTTP
types:
  value: string
  numbers:
    type: value[]
    xml:
      wrapped: true

/claimDemo:
  post: 
   body:
    type: numbers
   responses: 
    200:
     body: 
      application/json:
       example: |
              {
                "message" : "Hello World"
              }
```

As an additional side note, to demonstrate where the error is coming from in your initial example, if you removed the array definition ie: changed:

```
  numbers:
    type: value[]
    uniqueItems: true
```

to

```
  numbers:
    type: value
```

Then you would have been able to use an input as below:

```
<numbers value="a">
```

Comment: Hi Matt , The whole idea is to make sure that value is an array of number not a single value

Comment: The first part of the response demonstrates how to achieve something like what you are after with the full example. The second part demonstrates an alternative, that demonstrates why you original sample does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Claim Request
version: 0.1
baseUri: http://localhost:8767/claim
mediaType: [ application/xml ]
protocols: HTTP
types:
  value:
    type: string
  numbers:
    type: value[]
    maxItems: 3
    uniqueItems: true
/claimDemo:
  post: 
   body:
    type : numbers
   responses: 
    200:
     body: 
      application/xml:
       example: |
              {
                "message" : "Hello World"
              }
```

Comment: Hi Rafael I am still getting the same error


Message               : Error validating XML. Error: s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'maxOccurs' cannot appear in element 'element'.
Payload               : java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@669b21b6
Element               : /arrayApi-main/processors/0 @ ramlwitharrays:arrayApi.xml:10 (APIkit Router)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error validating XML. Error: s4s-att-not-allowed: Attribute 'maxOccurs' cannot appear in element 'element'.